# unexpected behavior with PHP extract() function

Tags: php

I was trying to figure out  the behavior of `EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS` flag in `extract()` function. But when I run my code, it adds more than the desired number of variables(two in this case) to current symbol table as indicated by the line:variables added. The output indicates three variables were added instead of two and variable 'key3' exists. Now I can't figure out what's causing this behavior or whether I misunderstood this concept. I'm new to PHP. Any help will be really appreciated.

my code:

```
$key1 = 'old';
$key2 = 'old';
$my_array = array (
    'key1'  => 'new value1',
    'key2'  => 'new value2',
    'key3'  => 'new value3'
);

$num = extract ($my_array, EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS, "prefixed");
echo "variables added:$num<br />"; //number of variables imported to symbol table
echo isset($key1) ? 'TRUE': 'FALSE';
echo "<br />";// true
echo isset($prefixed_key3) ? 'TRUE': 'FALSE'; 
echo "<br />";
echo isset($key3) ? 'TRUE': 'FALSE';// should output false
```

output:

variables added:3
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE

Comment: Try `print_r(get_defined_vars());` which will show you what variables are defined (and so which ones you create)

Comment: I did as Nigel said and it works!. now it displays only two variables were added. thanks Nigel.

Comment: That's really weird because adding a `print_r` shouldn't have changed the output... the behaviour you were seeing was definitely incorrect, you should only see that behaviour with the `EXTR_PREFIX_SAME` flag. [This demo on rextester](http://rextester.com/DXG8487) demonstrates the correct behaviour of each flag.

Comment: @Nick - it shouldn't (and I think your answer is correct, so worth undeleting), the suggestion was more a debugging aid than an answer.

Comment: @NigelRen actually my answer was wrong, I had the flag behaviour mixed up with  `EXTR_PREFIX_SAME`. One wonders if OP had changed the flag but then not uploaded the new code???

Answer (score 1):

```
 EXTR_PREFIX_IF_EXISTS
```

means **prefix existing variable name when name collisions occur before extracting the variable to the scope and create a new variable if no collision occurs**.In your case you didn't define `$Key3` anywhere before the `extract` function so the actual behavior is completely normal...

In your code extract proceed actually this way:

loop through your array and check if the variable already exists. If it exists, according to your flag, create a new variable with the name `prefix+_+the existing name` .
In your case you already defined `$key1 and $key2` before the use of `extract` so 2 variables are created with prefixed name but as already said the variable `$key3` is undefined before `extract` so it creates one more variable without prefix .Thus make the number of variables added correct(*3 in your case*).